# Load with opencv an image saved with tifffile

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to load with *opencv* an image that I previously saved with *tifffile*, because the image has 5 channels and opencv max supported channels are 4.

#### Saving

```
shape: (256, 256, 5)  
tifffile.imwrite('image_name.png/.tiff', image)
```

#### Loading

```
new_image = cv2.imread('image_name.png/.tiff')  
new_image shape: (256, 5) <-- Why?
```

How can I solve this problem?
Or how can I save a 5 channel image in **png** format and then reload it with opencv?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga4dd47c9ae3d55cc42286cff005825e31

Comment: `(256, 5) <-- Why?` because you are saving 256 x (256, 5) images in a multi-page TIFF.  To save a multi-channel image in a single-page TIFF use `imwrite('name.tif', image, planarconfig='CONTIG')`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a 5-channel image in a PNG file because PNG can only support a maximum of 4 channels, namely RGBA.

If you want 5-channels, you'll need TIFF as you rightly say... which begs the question why don't you read the file back with `tifffile`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn’t know that PNG support was of maximum 4 channels. I can’t read the file back with tfffile because I’m making a script to read the file back both from local and from google-cloud-storage. I usually use joblib + tf.io.gfile.GFile to read bytes of the image directly from google-cloud-storage’s bucket and then I use np.frombuffer to trasform them into a matrix (cv2 image). Unfortunately I’ve found no way to load images from gcs using tifffile!